# Performing application reliability using iis 6/7

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, iis, reliability

I have web-services applications, running on Windows Server 2003. These hosts (each of them on separate appPool) contains multiple operations (consulting services).
Does exist an approach to perform reliability on these hosts, in terms of appPools (like customizing the pools): *If an worker process fails, another will be started in its place*.

If there is a way to perform it in IIS 7 - or using WCF - I would appreciate the information.

Thanks

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific and precise.  Asking how to "perform reliability" is much too vague.

Comment: I just edited the question. I mean like having a contingency for the pool.

Comment: You _still_ need to be more specific. What do you mean, "having a contingency for the pool"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is resiliency built-in to the IIS6/7 process model.  If an worker process fails, another will be started in its place. If that is what you mean, then YES, you can get reliability. See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/10cd7224-3d8a-41c8-9ff2-909bb578a4ea.mspx for more info.

I don't know what "take a contingency" means.

HTTP requests that are "in flight" when a process crash occurs, are lost.  The client must resubmit the request.  If you need to reliability for that scenario, you'll need a different approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I corrected the question. I will study the implementation of AppPool Health Monitoring and Rapid-Fail Protection. In this application scenario, we can accept the lose of a request "in flight", if another worker process takes place immediately.